# tidyverse/stringr how to find and replace on exact matches

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I am trying to perform find and replace function. Prior sleuthing indicates this should be possible with `stringr::str_replace` and `stringr::str_replace_all`. However, I'm running into issues because partial matches in longer strings lead to unwanted results. I want the pattern argument to match the whole string not just portions of strings; when it is just a portion I want the replacement operation to ignore the cell. I would greatly appreciate any insight on how to accomplish exact match find and replace operations preferably in a `mutate` statement.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~col1,
  "foo",
  "foo bar",
  "foo",
  "foo bar",
  "pizza"
)
```

Then to find and replace, what I see is commonly the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, pattern = "foo", replacement = "foo bar"))
```

Unfortunately, this produces unwanted results:

```
foo bar             
foo bar bar             
foo bar             
foo bar bar
pizza
```

I'm looking to get:

```
foo bar             
foo bar         
foo bar             
foo bar
pizza
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `^` and `$` to suggest the start and end of the string so that it matches only the cases where 'foo' is the only word (Note that `str_replace` would also work fine as we are doing a single replacement here)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(col1 = str_replace_all(col1, 
            pattern = "^foo$", replacement = "foo bar"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  col1   
  <chr>  
1 foo bar
2 foo bar
3 foo bar
4 foo bar
```

---

Based on the example, we just need

```
df$col1 <- "foo bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, the use of ^ and $ works well in the example, but isn't translating to the wild data set. I must have some other issue to iron out. The last solution works in the reprex, but the wild data set has many other rows. I should have constructed a reprex that made this fact clearer; editing the question now.

Comment: @ncraig May be there is some leading/lagging spaces in the column.  Try by `df$col1 <- trimws(df$col1)` and apply the code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need negative lookahead.  Let me show you on an modified example-

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~col1,
  "foo pizza",
  "foo bar",
  "foo",
  "foo bar",
  "pizza"
)

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   col1     
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 foo pizza
#> 2 foo bar  
#> 3 foo      
#> 4 foo bar  
#> 5 pizza

df %>% mutate(col1 = str_replace(col1, 'foo(?!\\sbar)', 'foo bar'))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   col1         
#>   <chr>        
#> 1 foo bar pizza
#> 2 foo bar      
#> 3 foo bar      
#> 4 foo bar      
#> 5 pizza
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing an exact match instead of using regex you can use `==` for direct comparison.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(col1 = replace(col1, col1 == 'foo', 'foo bar'))

#   col1   
#  <chr>  
#1 foo bar
#2 foo bar
#3 foo bar
#4 foo bar
#5 pizza
```

Also you can do -

```
df$col1[df$col1 == 'foo'] <- 'foo bar'
```